# python better way to set dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

what is a better way to do this  in python
current = {}

```
    if key in current:
        current[key] += 1
    else:
        current[key] = 1
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Post post a [mcve] and look up collections.Counter

Comment: Better how? This is readable and efficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Frequency mapping with dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487564/frequency-mapping-with-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: @PCM I guess increment or initialize

Comment: You can use `defaultdict(int)` or `current.get(key, 0)+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setdefault`:

```
current = {}
a = ['a', 'b', 'a']
for i in a:
    current[i] = current.setdefault(i, 0) + 1
print(current)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Or use `get`:

```
current = {}
a = ['a', 'b', 'a']
for i in a:
    current[i] = current.get(i, 0) + 1
```

Or if you want to get the frequency count:

```
from collections import Counter
a = ['a', 'b', 'a']
current = Counter(a)
print(current)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using defaultdict has some advantages over the builtin dict functionality. For one thing, it's more efficient to do this type of uninitialized increment using one lookup rather than two lookups.

```
from collections import defaultdict
current = defaultdict(int)
current[key] += 1
```

With dict on the other hand, no matter how you write it you still have to do a separate lookup for get and then set.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code for this, `defaultdict(int)` will add the key with a default value if it is absent:

```
from collections import defaultdict
current = defaultdict(int)

keys = ['a','b', 'c', 'a']

for key in keys:
    current[key]+=1
print (current)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1})
```

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/defaultdict-in-python/) is the nice document for `defaultdict` behavior and how it achieves it.